# Refactoring Code, Make parameter optional with if

Tags: c#

I have code, sometimes I need to fill "Parameter1" with something and sometimes not, could I refactoring the code so I dont need to repeat code like:  Name = "Adam", with If or something?

```
 public class Address
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var VariableParameter1_On = false;
        var address = new Address();
        if (VariableParameter1_On)
        {
            address = new Address
            {
                Name = "Adam",
                City = "Paris",
                Parameter1 = "Test"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            address = new Address
            {
                Name = "Adam",
                City = "Paris",
                Parameter1 = "Test"  //Make this optional with if?
            };
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: Set Name & City in the constructor then decide if you need to `address.Parameter1 = "Test"` after the fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the field to `null` might be what you are looking for ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/null)). We can also use an [inline if statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

Replace your `Main` method with:

```
var VariableParameter1_On = false;
var address = new Address
{
    Name = "Adam",
    City = "Paris",
    Parameter1 = VariableParameter1_On ? "Test" : null;
};

Console.ReadKey();
```

I assume that `Parameter1` is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) (e.g. a class), which can be set to `null`, and not a value type (e.g. a struct or enum), which *must* be assigned a value.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to instantiate the object with the values for Name and City in either case. The only optional part is `Parameter1`'s value, or lack thereof.

Your current code instantiates an empty `Address` object, and then immediately re-assigns it. All you really need to do is instantiate a new `Address` with the values for `Name` and `Address` assigned, then assign `Parameter1` in your `if` statement

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var VariableParameter1_On = false;
        var address = new Address { Name = "Adam", City = "Paris" };

        if (VariableParameter1_On)
            address.Parameter1 = "Test";


        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a constructor with an optional parameter.

```
//Both these calling examples are fine.
Address a = new Address("Peter", "New york");
Address b = new Address("Peter", "New york", "some parameter");

public class Address
{
    public Address(string name, string city, string parameter1 = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        City = city;
        Parameter1 = parameter1;
    }

    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
    public string Parameter1{ get; set; }
}
```

Then initialize a variable, maybe set it, always pass it to Address's constructor.

```
var parameter = null;
//Does not matter if the method returns an empty string or an actual value, we initialized it and will pass it anyway.
parameter = SetParameterBasedOnSettingsOrWhatever();
Address b = new Address("Peter", "New york", parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use types as often as you can just in sake of readability and good naming.
Maybe you can try to encapsulate the check in a specific method too to improve readability.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool isParamaterMandatory = true;
    Address address = new Address()
    {
        City = "Paris",
        Name = "Adam",
        Parameter1 = GetParameterIfNeeded(isParamaterMandatory)
    };

    Console.ReadKey();

}

private static string GetParameterIfNeeded(bool isNeeded)
{
    if (isNeeded)
    {
        return "Mandatory";
    }

    return null;
}
```